# Convergence of power series beyond radius of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

In rudin analysis text book, **3.44 theorem** , it says about the convergence on the boundary of the circle of the power series, the theorem is roughly:-

> Suppose the radius of convergence of $\Sigma c_nz^n $ and suppose the $c_n$ series is monotonically decreasing$c_n->0 $ as n-> infinity. Then $\Sigma c_nz^n $ converges at every point of mod z = 1 except possibly at z=1.

**My question is :-**

> Why would not the same proof applies under the given hypothesis for when the radius of convergence is $<1$ ?

But if the proof is true for that case too then is not it a contradiction to **3.39 theorem** (as there would be points mod z = 1 may not be z=1 such that the series converges that is the series is converging beyond the radius of convergence)(so where am I mistaking?)(saying about the existence of a radius of convergence) ?

Well and in **3.42 theorem** ('partial sums of series of $a_n$ is bounded' and ' $ b_n$ decreases monotonically' and $b_n->0$ ' the $\Sigma a_nb_n$ converges.) saying about convergence of series of $a_nb_n$ do the series $a_n$ needs to converge ?

Comment: This question is not very accessible if one hasn't this book at hand.

Comment: How about just giving the statements of the theorems?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://math.feld.cvut.cz/hekrdla/Teaching/XP01MTS/Miscell/E7S12Y8EkN4RRtY/Principles_of_mathematical_analysis_Rudin.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjmrrrjheThAhUET48KHa7DASsQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0MwEKeAR7TqAGpKAy3jSpQ

Comment: Here is the book

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so now an answer to the question might be appreciated.

Comment: Your last question should be another post.

Comment: Going through the proof of the theorem might make my question clearer.

Comment: If the radius of convergence is $R$ then the last phrase of the theorem becomes, "except perhaps at $z=R$."

Comment: @saulspatz No that is the thing I am saying

Comment: What do you mean?  What is the thing you are saying?

Comment: In that case too the so called $A_n$ ( that is the partial sum) is bounded for z=1.

Comment: "Beyond" is the **wrong** world.

Answer (score 1):

In the proof of Theorem 3.44, Rudin appeals to Theorem 3.42.  He says,"the hypotheses of Theorem 3.42 are satisfied."  This is **not** true if the radius of convergence is less than $1$.  The first hypothesis of theorem 3.42 is, "the partial sums form a bounded sequence."  If the radius of convergence is less than $1$ and $|z|=1$ then the partial sums are certainly not bounded.

Comment: **In the inequality the one given in rudin, plug 1 in place of the mod z (after applying triangle inequality offcourse in the numerator) and hence the rhs of inequality remains unchanged, so of course the $A_n$ .** Is my reasoning wrong anywhere in that case please point it and clarify it, thanks for your time and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In an entire series, say

$$\sum c_n z^n,$$ if the radius of convergence is $1$, the modified series

$$\sum c_n\left(\frac zr\right)^n=\sum\frac{c_n}{r^n}z^n$$ has the radius of convergence $r$. Hence any proof can be easily adapted to non-unit radii.

Comment: Well I did not get your answer actually could you please explain?

Comment: @BijayanRay: what part don't you understand ?

Comment: I am saying that the power series is converging beyond the radius of convergence my arguments are in the question where am I wrong?

Comment: @BijayanRay: even more confuse than before, sorry.

Comment: Going through the proof of the theorem might make my question clearer.

Comment: @BijayanRay: the theorems are perfectly clear and well-known.

Comment: My question is basically, I am claiming when you are changing the radius of convergence the in the boundary of circle under consideration has radius still 1 (do not it ? As it comes from the gp formula (acting as the upper bound in rudin proof)) so am I mistaking anywhere?

Comment: @BijayanRay: spend some effort to make your explanations intelligible.